# Create custom parameters (options) for already existing commands?

Tags: bash, command, pacman, options, parameter

Recently I 've been wanting to create a custom parameter for `pacman`.

To elaborate, I have tweaked `pacman.conf` so that specific packages (`linux`, `linux-firmware`, and a couple more) are ignored when I use `# pacman -Syu` to upgrade all packages - unless they are explicitly mentioned (eg. `# pacman -Syu linux linux-firmware`).

So what I want now is a parameter to use instead of mentioning each package that is normally ignored.

Summing it up, I want to create a parameter (say `--param`) so that `# pacman -Syu --param` be equivalent to `# pacman -Syu linux linux-firmware linux-headers ...`.

---

1. Trying to implement this using aliases seems to be impossible (unless I've missed something).
2. A parameter to allow upgrading **all** ignored packages would be welcome, albeit not ideal. It also seems to me that it would be far more difficult to construct.
3. I'm currently using `bash` (and sometimes `zsh`) - I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: You could use a function. Those allow passing parameters. Or a wrapper script.

Comment: Or you can create an alias.

Answer (score 0):

First, this is a terrible idea. `IgnorePkg` is meant to be a temporary measure as it is essentially forcing [partial upgrades](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_maintenance#Partial_upgrades_are_unsupported), not something that is your *de facto* approach to package management for a rolling release.

Having said that, it would be relatively straightforward to create a function to achieve your goal.

```
fullupgrade() { pacman -Syu $(awk -F= '/^IgnorePkg/ {print $NF}' /etc/pacman.conf) ; }
```